# VBA Yes No link to click

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

I am very new in HTML and VBA. In HTML page I have option to click "Yes" or "No". Note these not buttons but links. Need help in VBA excel code to click on "Yes" or "No". More interested in "Yes". "NO" I can ignore by using IE.Quit

HTML Code for Yes or No

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<Table>
<TR>
<TD>
<A HREF="Abc.com"><FONT COLOR="#8000080">YES<Font></A>
&nbsp; <HREF="javascript:window.close();"><FONT COLOR="#8000080">NO<Font></A>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Try This `IE.document.getelementsbytagname("a")(1).innertext.click` OR it might be "innerHTML" not "innertext"

Comment: Thanks. Will try tomorrow and seek further help if face issues.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what your looking for. It will prompt users with a question and they will be able to choose "yes" or "no" in VBA

```
Sub question()
  answer = MsgBox("your question", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "subject")
  If answer = vbYes Then
       'Do This
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I am looking for something like responded by user1. I am able to activate html link using  VBA but next screen pops up with Yes or No in HTML and need VBA code to automatically click Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. Basically you want to iterate over all the `A` tags and find where the innerText is a match to yes. Once that is done, you can click the element.

```
Sub ClickYes()
    Dim ie        As Object: Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Dim elements  As Object
    Dim element   As Object

    ie.navigate "mysite.com"

    'Wait until the page loads
    Do Until ie.readystate <> 4
        Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
        DoEvents
    Loop

    ie.Visible = True

    Set elements = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

    'Make sure we got an object back, otherwise exit
    If elements Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'Iterate through the a elements and click where the innertext is yes
    For Each element In elements
        'turn error handling off
        On Error Resume Next

        'Click the link where the text is Yes
        If element.innerText = "Yes" Then
            element.Click
            Exit For ' stop searching after the first match
        End If
    Next

    'turn error handling back on
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan. It worked to some extent but click didn't work. Instead of click I used is.navigate element and it worked. In the other pop when there was no A tag in the HTML VBA must have exit at line if elements is Nothing Then Exit sub, but it exists in the next line for each element in elements. 

With I used ie.navigate element it would navigate the first url available, that may be risky because different pop up may have different h ref. I would like to use ie.navigate if the url within hyperlink contains a specific text. Inner text = "yes" didn't work.Is there any code for like or contains

Comment: Sorry for typos. Using phone

Comment: I used innterHTML Like "*close*" then element.click also work.